# Delphi Post Values to php file but cannot access values from PHP files

Tags: php, delphi, tms

I am using delphi to post values to a php file for processing. I am using [TWebPost from TMS](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/webpost.asp) and previously the module worked perfectly except for replacing all the spaces with a `+` now however i have tried to change the `PostContentType` from `ctFormURLEncoded` to `ctMultiPartForm` as they recommended.

Since the change I can no longer access the variables I post using the `$_POST` function in PHP.

Anybody have an idea on how the PHP file can access the variables?

Comment: This is odd, no TWebPost [on this page](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/manuals.asp)

Comment: Hi @StijnSanders that is very odd.
But i had a quick look and found it on this page http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/webpost.asp

Answer (score 1):

There are same small example for using TWebPost and php script in a Delphi.

This example UwpdemoVersionProgram I was do based on the GitHub demo example for TWebPost link [demo for Uwpdemo.pas](https://github.com/tmssoftware/TMS-Component-Pack-demos/tree/master/WebPost)
But better will be if you register at GitHub page  [page for registering in a GitHub server](https://github.com/join?return_to=%2Ftmssoftware%2FTMS-Component-Pack-demos&source=login)
GitHub is a repository for many project , where developer can put own project and get acces to many project from other's developer's . After registering you can download many examples in a one ziped file .

```
unit UwpdemoVersionProgram;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  WebPost, StdCtrls, ShellApi;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  WebPost1: TWebPost;
  Button1: TButton;
  procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
   procedure GetVersionProgramFromRemote(var StringReceivedFromRemote:  AnsiString);
  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  implementation
 {$R *.DFM}
 procedure TForm1.GetVersionProgramFromRemote(var StringReceivedFromRemote:  AnsiString);
var
 wpi:twebpostitem;
 Response: TMemoryStream;
 StrResponse: AnsiString ;
 begin
 Response := TMemoryStream.Create;
 webpost1.Server:='your_sever.com';;  //cannot be with http://
 webpost1.Action:='/subdirectory/GetVersionProgram_Post.php'; //  script php  with it will be cooperating program from Delphi
  webpost1.items.Clear;
 with webpost1.items do
  begin
   wpi:=add;
   wpi.name:='Name_program';
   wpi.value:= 'AWARD_SECRETARY.exe';
    //if you want obtain more data , repeat this there above lines with another's parameters
  end;
 if webpost1.execute then
  begin
   webpost1.savetofile('results.txt');
   Response:= TMemoryStream(webpost1.PostResult);
   StrResponse:=AnsiString( Response);
   StringReceivedFromRemote:=StrResponse;
   end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var StringReceivedFromRemote: AnsiString;
  begin
   GetVersionProgramFromRemote(StringReceivedFromRemote);
  end;
----------------------------------------------------------------
 Php script GetVersionProgram_Post.php is as follow
<?PHP
include ('info.php');
 $link = mysql_connect($db_server, $db_username, $db_password);
 if (!$link) {
    die('Cannot conect : ' . mysql_error());
 }
 echo 'Connect was do '.chr(13)  ;
 mysql_select_db($db_database);
$Name_program=$_POST['Name_program'];   //this work work with  TWebPost - but value must be present not in a URL
                                                                            // but only in a webpost1.items  as this wpi.value:= 'AWARD_SECRETARY.exe';
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM ACTUAL_PROGRAM_VERSION WHERE NAME_PROGRAM = '$Name_program' ");
 if (!$result) {
    echo 'Cannot run query : ' . mysql_error();
   exit;
 }
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo $row[0].chr(13)   ; // NAME_PROGRAM
echo $row[1].chr(13)   ; // ACTUAL_VERSION
echo $row[2].chr(13)   ; // CREATION_DATE
echo $row[3].chr(13)   ; // ID_PROGRAM
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Structure in a MYSQL is:

```
   NAME_PROGRAM    varchar(32)
   ACTUAL_VERSION  varchar(32)
   CREATION_DATE   varchar(12)
   ID_PROGRAM      int(11)
```

Comment: Formatting would be helpful